# How come evaporation is possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

If I have wet clothes and put them on the ground and let the Sun shine on them, they dry as water evaporates. But water should evaporate at 100 degrees Celsius so how come they go dry if it's just about 30 degrees Celsius? What am I missing?

Comment: @DavePhD: Yep, the question is answered entirely in the link.

Comment: Read the [Feynman's Lectures on Physics Volume I](http://zeth.ciencias.uchile.cl/~rosorio/Mecanica/Libros/Feynman%20-%20Lectures%20on%20physics%20volumen%201%20(ingles).pdf) (first few pages). You will get your question answered in the way you want.